# Deleting element from a tuple's list

Tags: haskell, tuples

I am having trouble writing a function which deletes an element from a list within a tuple.

The problem is, I would like the function to return the tuple. However, using the `delete` function from `Data.List` gives me a list.

Code:

```
-- type Value = Int
type Cell = (Int, [Int])
type Board = [Cell]

----------- your solution goes here --------------


-- solvem :: Board -> Board
-- solvem bd = ???
deleteCandidate :: Int -> Cell -> Cell
deleteCandidate cand c1 = delete cand (snd c1) -- This gives me trouble

updateNeighbors :: Cell -> Cell -> Cell
updateNeighbors c1 c2 | isNeighbor c1 c2 = deleteCandidate (head (snd c1)) c2
                      | otherwise = c2
```

Since data in Haskell is immutable, how would I return a tuple in `deleteCandidate` function? Would I have to reconstruct a Cell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply pattern-match the tuple to extract the two pieces, operate on one of them, and then put it back together into a new tuple:

```
deleteCandidate :: Int -> Cell -> Cell
deleteCandidate cand (x, xs) = (x, delete cand xs)
```

Alternatively, since `(a,)` has a `Functor` instance, you could write

```
deleteCandidate :: Int -> Cell -> Cell
deleteCandidate cand = fmap (delete cand)
```

Or, shorter still, you could elide the explicit `cand` argument as well, and express deleteCandidate as a simple function composition:

```
deleteCandidate :: Int -> Cell -> Cell
deleteCandidate = fmap . delete
```

Personally I like the second version best, because I find it hard to think about how this composition works, and how it's different from `(fmap delete)`.